# Keep getting same permalink with WP_Query?

Tags: posts, wp-query, permalinks, links

I have this code below, and I wish to show each link of each post, but I keep getting same link to all posts which is the link of the page.

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 5,'order' => 'DESC');
$rp = new WP_Query($args);
if($rp->have_posts()) :
while($rp->have_posts()) : $rp->the_post();

   the_title(); 

$link=the_permalink();
echo '<a href="'.$link.'">Welcome</a>';
echo "<br />";

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata(); 

endif;
```

Thank you.

Comment: This might not solve your problem, but i wonder why you are storing your permalinks in a variable. You can use it directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't forget to use `esc_url()`

```
echo '<a href="'. esc_url( $link ).'">Welcome</a>';
```

Also try this: `get_permalink( get_the_ID() );`

Comment: the esc_url() didn't help, I get same result. The second command just works fine :) , thank you

Comment: It's important to use escaping functions such as esc_url, esc_html, esc_attr for safety reasons. :) This url might be helpful to you: [WordPress Escape Functions](https://codeseekah.com/2012/03/13/wordpress-escape-functions/)

Comment: could you tell please, why when using the_permalink(); alone without echo or anything else, it would work while when using it as a link or href as above it does not work?

Comment: Maybe this website could clear things up for you: [get_permalink WP Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'order' => 'DESC');
$rp   = new WP_Query($args);
if ($rp->have_posts()) :
    $i    = 0;
    $link = '';
    while ($rp->have_posts()) : $rp->the_post();
        the_title();
        if ($i == 0) $link = get_permalink();

        echo '<a href="' . $link . '">Welcome</a>';
        echo "<br />";
        $i++;
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```

this core get only first post link

Answer (score 0):

You are missing get_the_ID() inside the loop. Thats why its showing the permalink of first post for each post inside the loop;

Try this code

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 5,'order' => 'DESC');
$rp = new WP_Query($args);
if($rp->have_posts()) :
while($rp->have_posts()) : $rp->the_post();

   the_title(); 

$link=get_the_permalink(get_the_ID()); //get_the_ID() gets the id of the post inside a loop
echo '<a href="'.$link.'">Welcome</a>';
echo "<br />";

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata(); 

endif;
```

**Note:** Please check the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) for better understanding.

Comment: the thing is when using the_permalink(); without any addition like echo before it, it works :\